# Getting PHP Warning array_sum() expects parameter 1 to be array, object given?

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, mysqli

Just trying to get the sum of a query result and I get:

> array_sum() expects parameter 1 to be array, object given

With the code:

```
function getPerformance($limit, $mysqli) {
    if (is_numeric($limit)) {
        $limit = 'LIMIT '.$limit;
    } else {
        $limit = NULL;
    }
    if ($stmt = $mysqli->query("SELECT time FROM admin_performance ORDER BY id DESC $limit")) {
        $average = array_sum($stmt) / count($stmt);
        $average = number_format(($average*1000),2,'.',',');
    } else {
        $average = 'Error';
    }
    return $average;
}
```

I also tried using $array = mysqli_fetch_array($stmt) after the query and changing array_sum($stmt) to array_sum($array) and got the same thing.

I got around it with this:

```
function getPerformance($limit, $mysqli) {
    if (is_numeric($limit)) {
        $limit = 'LIMIT '.$limit;
    } else {
        $limit = NULL;
    }
    if ($stmt = $mysqli->query("SELECT time FROM admin_performance ORDER BY id DESC $limit")) {
        $rows = mysqli_num_rows($stmt);
        $sum = 0;
        while ($array = mysqli_fetch_array($stmt)) {
            $sum += $array['time'];
        }
        $average = $sum/$rows;
        $average = number_format(($average*1000),2,'.',',');
    } else {
        $average = 'Error';
    }
    return $average;
}
```

But what was I doing wrong? I imagine it's more efficient without a while() loop.

Comment: `$stmt` is a `mysqli_result`, not an array.

Comment: Why are you calculating the average in PHP? Use `SELECT AVG(time)` in SQL.

Comment: Isn't it an array after mysqli_fetch_result()?

Comment: And I didn't know I could do that in SQL! That's probably a much better option!

Comment: There's no such function as `mysqli_fetch_result()`.

Comment: You're right, I meant mysqli_fetch_array(), was a typo in the question.

Comment: `mysqli_fetch_array()` just returns an array containing one row of the results, not all the results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`$stmt` is a `mysqli_result`, not an array of the values in the query. You have to call a fetch function to get the values. And the fetch function just returns one row at a time, not an array of all the results.

If you have the MYSQLND driver, you can use `$stmt->fetch_all()`. This returns a 2-dimensional array -- each row of the array is a row of the results. You can't use `array_sum()` on this, because it requires a 1-dimensional array of the values. But you could use `array_column()` to return an array of a particular column of that, then sum that.

```
$rows = $stmt->fetch_all();
$average = array_sum(array_column($rows, 'time')) / count($rows);
```

But a more efficient way would be to calculate the average in SQL.

```
if ($stmt = $mysqli->query("SELECT AVG(time) AS avgtime FROM (SELECT time FROM admin_performance ORDER BY id DESC $limit) AS x")) {
    $row = $stmt->fetch_assoc();
    $average = $row['avgtime'];
} else {
    die($mysqli->error);
}
```

Comment: I liked your recommendation. What about this?: `SELECT AVG(time) AS avgtime FROM admin_performance ORDER BY id DESC $limit`

Comment: That won't work. `LIMIT` applies to the result *after* calculating the average, which is just one row. It doesn't apply to the rows being used in calculating the average.

Comment: That's why `ORDER BY` and `LIMIT` have to be done in a subquery.